# Center a ProgressBar in a Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have a custom dialog (inherited from `android.app.Dialog`) with no title or border. To this dialog I add a normal `ProgressBar`, and would like to center it in the dialog. The dialog itself has a background image that stretches for the full screen. Everything seems to work except that the progress bar is not getting centered in the dialog. It looks like this:

[image: ProgBar Not Centered in Dialog]

This is the code I have used within the customDialog class, to add the progress bar to the dialog:

```
ProgressBar progBar = new ProgressBar(context);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
addContentView(progBar, layoutParams);

getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Is there something I'm missing, or getting wrong?

Comment: [check the layout of my answer might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android/13342157#13342157)

Comment: Use Relative layout instead of Linear layout

Comment: @chintankhetiya, If there is minimal change in my existing code to correct it, I'll use that. If not, I'll try out your solution

Comment: @BasimSherif, I used RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout, but I did not see any change

Comment: You want to do it programatically or through layout?

Comment: @Noman, preferably programmatically

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
    ProgressBar progBar = new ProgressBar(context);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, progBar.getId());
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, progBar.getId());

    parentLayout.addView(progBar, lp);
```

Comment: This did not work. Btw, there is no addView for Dialog, so I used addContentView

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)b.getLayoutParams();    
ll.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
progBar.setLayoutParams(ll);
```

Comment: Now I can't see the ProgressBar at all

Comment: Try my solution using Relative layout

Comment: Can I see your dialog fragment layout xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Set layout hight and width `FILL_PARENT`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
progBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```